# Google Places implementation radius limitation workaround

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am designing a google places implementation with google maps in my app. 
If I query Google Places there is a limitation of 50000m or 50 km to the search radius.

Say I am in Spain I want to search for a place in Italy. How would I get returns for that from my search?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the location in your places query to be in Italy. You can use the geocoder to find convert the location to a LatLng

Comment: I know how to set my location to Italy with the geocoder. I guess I am trying to replicate the Google Maps search bar. So that you just type in a place and it spits out the results. Is there any way to do that with the Google Places API?

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I am trying to replicate the Google Maps search bar. So that
>   you just type in a place and it spits out the results. Is there any
>   way to do that with the Google Places API?

You can use Google Places AutoComplete API to do that. It uses a text based search like "Pizza in Italy"

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Pizza+in+Italy&types=geocode&language=fr&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```